# Take only digit as input by scanf() and avoid other characters

Tags: c++, io, scanf

I want to take the following format of input using `scanf()` until EOF that will avoid '+' sign and store only integer value.

Input sample:

```
1+2+8
```

Output for the above input:

```
1 2 8
```

I wrote the following code for this:

```
 while(scanf("%d+",&tmp)) //here 'tmp' is int type variable
 {
    v.push_back(tmp);   //'v' is vector<int> type
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
 {
    cout<<v[i]<<" ";
 }
```

Unfortunately, the while loop works as a infinite loop. What will be the solution for this problem?

Comment: when you write c++, why do you want to use `scanf` when the job can be done much easier with c++ streams?

Comment: can you please help me by writing the code ?

Comment: One easy solution is to just read a full line, then split it using "+" as a delimiter

Comment: It near.but not the answer. @Nathanael Demacon

Comment: @ImtiazMehedi Is there a specific reason you are using *scanf*? If you use *cin* object, it ll be more easy.

Comment: Yes there is a reason behind using scanf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `std::cin` solution

Since you are already using `std::cout`<sup>1</sup>, you can use `std::cin` instead of `scanf`.  Now, read the number first, and handle the sign after:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
for (int n; std::cin >> n;) {
    numbers.push_back(n);
    if (std::cin.peek() == '+') { // if the next character is '+'
        std::cin.get();           // then discard it
    }
}
```

## `scanf` solution

If you insist on using `scanf` (in which case you probably should be using `printf` as well), you can use the ignore functionality of the control string of `scanf`:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
for (int n; std::scanf("%d%*1[+]", &n) == 1;) { // optionally discard '+' after number
    numbers.push_back(n);
}
```

Let's break the `%*1[+]` *conversion specification* down:

- `%` — the beginning of every conversion specification;
- `*` — the result of this conversion should be discarded, rather than assigned to an argument;
- `1` — the width of the conversion (i.e., the maximum number of characters to convert); and
- `[+]` — the *format specifier* which means to match the longest string comprising `+` exclusively (subject to the width constraint, of course).

Altogether, this conversion specification means "discard at most one `+` character".

If no `+` sign is present, the `scanf` will return because consuming zero characters for a field results in a conversion error.  The next character will not be consumed (which is expected).

Note that `scanf` returns number of *receiving arguments* (arguments after the format string) successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned — see the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value) page.

---

<sup>1</sup> You are actually writing `cout`, which is hopefully `std::cout` brought in scope by `using std::cout` or `using namespace std;`.